# Error(7,11): PLS-00201: identifier 'NA.TITLE_ID' must be declared

Tags: database, oracle, compiler-errors

triggers are not working as expected and giving compilation error

Error(7,11): PLS-00201: identifier 'NA.TITLE_ID' must be declared

here is my trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER is_title_available  
BEFORE INSERT ON  rental  
REFERENCING OLD AS o NEW AS na
FOR EACH ROW  
WHEN (na.TITLE_ID > 0)  
DECLARE  
      isavailable  boolean;
      temp number;
      title_not_available EXCEPTION;

BEGIN  
   temp :=na.TITLE_ID;
   if(TITLE_AVAILABLE(temp)) then
   dbms_output.put_line('title available rent entry inserted');
   else 
   raise title_not_available;
   end if;

END;
```

and here is my table schema

```
CREATE TAble rental(
 BOOK_DATE date DEFAULT sysdate primary key,
 MEMBER_ID int,
 COPY_ID int ,
 TITLE_ID int,
 ACT_RET_DATE date,
 EXPIRY_RET_DATE date DEFAULT sysdate+2    
 );

 ALTER TABLE rental
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_member_rental
 FOREIGN KEY (MEMBER_ID)
 REFERENCES MEMBER(MEMBER_ID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below way 
:na.Title_ID

You need to use ':' (colon) to access value of new or old reference.